# How to disable all elements based on ID but not this one?

Tags: jquery

I've got the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$(this).siblings().prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: What is "the current one"?

Comment: How do you know what the current element is? I'm assuming you're running this code in an event handler? What is `i`? We really need to see more of your code in order to help you. It would also seem to make more sense to group the elements by class instead of incremental `id` attributes

Comment: `$('.whateverMatchesAll').not("#some_id"+ i).prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: @connexo, post it as an answer I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.not()` function to filter the item you don't want to be disabled:

```
$('.whateverMatchesAll').not("#some_id"+ i).prop("disabled", true)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this. You will get what you are looking for**

```js
$(document).on('click', 'p', function(){
   $("p").css('background-color', 'white') //clear
   all_except_current = $("p").not($(this))
   all_except_current.css('background-color', 'red')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<p>click me</p>
<p>click me</p>
<p>click me</p>
<p>click me</p>
<p>click me</p>
```